# Switch case (one case intersects another case)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

For example I have the following code;

```
switch ("SS") {
    case "SS":
        word = "hello";
        break;
    case "SSS":
        word = "bye";
        break;
}
```

I'm looking for SSS but when it sees the first SS, it matches with the first case and `word = hello`
 How can I modify the code when I have such situation where one case intersects another case?

Comment: The situation is same when you have string.

Comment: Invert the two cases?

Comment: I invert but the result is same. It goes to the "SS" case.

Comment: Rethink your example. Yes, it'll go to the `"SS"` case if you're switching on `"SS"`. It's unclear what you're really asking, especially now that's you've pulled the rug out from under all existing comments and answers.

Comment: When I edited the question and refresh the page, I see the answers:/ Sorry for all.

Answer (score 0):

make it switch condition as a string.

```
var condition = '0';// or '00'
switch (condition) {
    case '0':
        word = "hello";
        break;
    case '00':
        word = "bye";
        break;
}
```

Comment: `'00'` is an illegal character literal

Comment: @Holger you check it through browser console

Comment: Yes, I thinked in Java for a moment :-(

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as String and use this

```
switch ("00") {
case "0":
    word = "hello";
    break;
case "00":
    word = "bye";
    break;
```

}

Comment: But why are you using a String inside the case that instead a variable?

Comment: Switch on a constant expression is nonsense. There is nothing to switch on.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting so because 00 =0;
  If you want to achieve the desires result, use strings instead of numbers as below:

```
var condition = "00";
switch (condition) {
      case "0":
           word = console.log("hello");
           break;
       case "00":
           word = console.log("bye");
           break;
 }
```

Comment: Switch on a constant expression is nonsense. There is nothing to switch on.

Answer (score 0):

00 is incorrect as you are trying to pass this value as an integer. An integer can't begin with a 0 followed by something. In the background your 00 value gets transformed into a simple 0

If you want to keep your approach you should convert it into a string like `'00'`

and do it as following:

```
switch ('00') {
    case '0':
        word = "hello";
        break;
    case '00':
        word = "bye";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
switch ('00') {
    case '0':
        word = "hello";
        break;
    case '00':
        word = "bye";
        break;
}
```

Result is

bye

Answer (score 0):

`switch`ing on a *literal* `"SS"` will *always* take you to the `"SS"` case label (or the `default` - if supplied - if `"SS"` is missing as a case label).

Normally, you tend to switch on a *variable*, although the case *labels* will be constants.

If you want program control flow to continue into the `case` directly below another one, then drop the appropriate `break;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch("00")
{
case "0":
  console.log("Hello");break;
case "00":
  console.log("Bye");break;
}
```

Use string instead of number.
In case you have a number so change it to string within switch condition
i.e. switch(input.toString()){...}
This will work fine